# After using realloc the next pointer in array is lost

Tags: c, string, realloc

```
void operation2(char **p, int n, char *sir) {
    int i, move, k, xlen, ylen;
    char *x, *y, *q, separatori[] = " \'\",!?";
    x = strtok(sir, " ");
    y = strtok(NULL, " ");
    xlen = strlen(x);
    ylen = strlen(y);
    move = ylen - xlen;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        k = 0;
        while (strstr(p[i] + k, x)) {
            q = strstr(p[i] + k, x);
            if ((strchr(separatori, *(q - 1)) || q == p[i]) &&
                (*(q + xlen) == '\0' || strchr(separatori, *(q + xlen)))) {
                if (move > 0 && k == 0)
                    p[i] = realloc(p[i], (strlen(p[i]) + move * counter(p[i], x) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                q = strstr(p[i] + k, x);
                memmove(q + xlen + move, q + xlen, strlen(q + xlen) + 1);
                memcpy(q, y, ylen);
                k = strlen(p[i]) - strlen(q) + ylen;
                if (move < 0)
                    p[i] = realloc(p[i], (strlen(p[i]) + move + 1) * sizeof(char));
            } else
                k = k + xlen;
        }
        puts(p[i]);
    }
}
```

The code aims to find and replace a word (`x`) with a second one (`y`) in a text dynamically allocated in `**p`. They come in a string (`sir`) and are separated.
`move` stores the difference between the words that are obtained. `n` represents the number of lines in the text.

The word `x` must not be within another word hence the need to check for the separators.

If the conditions are met then the string is reallocated depending if the `move` is positive or negative. If it's positive the string will be longer and can be reallocated for all the apparitions of the word `x` inside of it. `counter` is a function that counts the apparitions in the string.
When `move` is negative the string must be diminished so the reallocation is done after the operations take place.

The replace is done with `memmove` and `memcpy`.

`k` is the position after the apparitions of `x`.

During a test there was the need to replace `"o"` with `"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"`.

This is the reference 
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD4AX.jpg)

And this is what I get
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiXzi.jpg)

When replacing `"o"` in the middle of the string an error occurs and the pointer to the next line is lost, pointing to the ending part of the previous line. The 1 represents the value of the counter for the line that follows

> Does `realloc` use memory that was already allocated and by doing so the next pointer is lost?

**EDIT:** Here is the allocation of the array:

```
int n, i;
scanf("%d", &n);
char **p, *aux;
p = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
aux = malloc(12000 * sizeof(char));
getchar();
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fgets(aux, 12000, stdin);
    p[i] = malloc((strlen(aux) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p[i], aux);
    p[i][strlen(p[i]) - 1] = '\0';
}
free(aux);
```

Comment: How do you initialize the array `p` points to? Do you allocate separate blocks for each line or do you use `strtok` to split a block into lines?

Comment: Replacing in place is error prone. You should allocate a destination buffer and copy from the source to the destination.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition. the multiplications are useless.

Comment: Ugh..  I would have used a char-by-char state machine instead of those nasty library calls.  It would then be possible to debug it without nightmares.

Comment: It does not look like the null character is accounted for in allocation nor copying.

Comment: compute `xlen` and `ylen` outside the loop and remove all these redundant `strlen()` calls.

Comment: I mean, 'if((strchr(separatori,*(q - 1)) || q == p[i]) && (*(q + strlen(x)) == '\0' || strchr(separatori, *(q + strlen(x)))))' takes too much mental effort to untangle and verify:(

Comment: @chux: you nailed it! write the answer.

Comment: There a re  LOT of strlen(x) calls:(

Comment: p=malloc(n * sizeof(char * ))
Then i use a for to read each line with fgets after i allocate it with malloc.

Comment: @chqrlie I see a problem, but I suspect there is a lot to fix.  Its up for anyone who wants to provide the details.  GTG

Comment: @chux: the missing '\0' does explain why lines get mixed up.  There are probably other issues, but this one is major.

Comment: @MartinJames But `q`, `p`, and `x` are self-explanatory! It could probably be deciphered in less than an hour.

Comment: @BarbuTudor: how exactly do you allocate each line?

Comment: Replacing `a` with `a` will cause an endless loop.  Replacing `a` with `aa` will run for a long time until memory is exhausted and null is dereferenced, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Added the allocation of the array in the question. as for a and aa that is what k is for

Comment: OK for `k`.  But `strchr(separatori,*(q - 1))` invokes undefined behavior if `q == p[i]` (a match at the beginning of the line).

Comment: You are not supposed to fix the question in place, it makes the comments and answers irrelevant.

Comment: Actually, not OK for `k`.  `k` is not updated correctly.  You should set `k` this way:  `k = q - p[i] + xlen;` if do not replace the match and `k = q - p[i] + ylen;` if you replace the match (your code works for this case but is cumbersome).

Comment: @chqrlie I will not modify the question any further. Thanks for letting me know. `q == p[i]` can only be true if the word that is searched for is at the beginning of the line

Comment: Changed the update of `k` but the error still persists

Comment: `p[i][strlen(p[i]) - 1] = '\0';`. Doesn't that overwrite the last byte of your string? `strcpy` should leave p[i] null terminated anyway.

Comment: @MillieSmith I needed to change it. Before that it was `'\n'`

Comment: Can you provide simple examples of `x` and `y` and what you expect the answer to be?

Comment: You have the string `"ale!is ?'Better than ,whale?and ale "`. And I take `"ale"` as x and `"wine"` as y. The result would be `"wine!is ?'Better than ,whale?and wine "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very confusing because of too many side effects, redundant calls to `strlen`...

The main issue is you do not allocate enough space for your strings: you forget the extra byte needed for the `'\0'` terminator.

You make this mistake in the main routine when you parse the file.

You make it again when you `realloc`ate the line.

You also forget to include the null byte when you `memmove` the contents of the line.

Fix these issues first.  There might be other ones, but you need to simplify your code to see them.  Read all the comments, there are many hints.

**EDIT:** You fixed your code in place, which may confuse other readers of this question, but you still have a mistake in the second call to `realloc`:

```
p[i] = realloc(p[i], (strlen(p[i]) + move + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

is incorrect because you already shortened the line, therefore `strlen(p[i])` is the new length.  Simply write:

```
p[i] = realloc(p[i], strlen(p[i]) + 1);
```

**EDIT:** Here is simpler version of `operation2` with fixes for most remarks in comments. I am not using `count` because since you did not post the code, I cannot assert that is does the right thing.

```
void operation2(char **p, int n, char *sir) {
    int i, move, k, xlen, ylen;
    static const char separatori[] = " \'\",!?";
    char *x, *y, *q;

    x = strtok(sir, " ");
    y = strtok(NULL, " ");
    xlen = strlen(x);
    ylen = strlen(y);
    move = ylen - xlen;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        k = 0;
        while ((q = strstr(p[i] + k, x)) != NULL) {
            k = q - p[i];
            if ((q == p[i] || strchr(separatori, q[-1])) &&
                (q[xlen] == '\0' || strchr(separatori, q[xlen]))) {
                if (move > 0) {
                    p[i] = realloc(p[i], strlen(p[i]) + move + 1);
                    q = p[i] + k;
                }
                memmove(q + ylen, q + xlen, strlen(q + xlen) + 1);
                memcpy(q, y, ylen);
                k += ylen;
                if (move < 0) {
                    p[i] = realloc(p[i], strlen(p[i]) + 1);
                }
            } else {
                k += xlen;
            }
        }
        puts(p[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the strlen calls for x and y. Also allocated the extra byte for '\0' in malloc and realloc. The effect still persist. This error did not happen if the replacement took place at the beginning of the line. As it can be seen in the pictures

Comment: @BarbuTudor: There might be a bug in the `count` function.  I posted a simpler version of `operation2()`.  Check if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Seems this solved the problem. Could it have been the fact that I didn't use `{ }` for the `if` branches? Or what do you suppose that caused the error?

Comment: @BarbuTudor: as I wrote in my answer, I suspect there is a bug in the  `count` function.  The braces do not seem at fault here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the C Standard is concerned, the behavior of realloc in all cases where it succeeds is equivalent to copying the memory block to some arbitrary location, calling free upon it, calling malloc to create a new block of the requested size, and returning a pointer to the new block (in cases where the malloc wouldn't succeed, realloc is defined to return null without disturbing the original block).  While many compilers usefully allowed a pointer to the old block to be compared with the new one, and would regard the difference between two pointers to the same object as being immutable and observable forever even after the lifetime of the object in question, the C Standard provides no means of querying whether a particular compiler supports such useful extensions.

As a result, if one wants code to be compatible with aggressive compilers, one must refrain from having any pointers point within an object which is going to be realloc'ed unless one can guarantee that such pointers will never even be *examined* after a successful realloc takes place.

Comment: Everything you write is true, but is not relevant here: the OP does not keep pointers in the reallocated block.  He recomputes `q` from `p[i]` for each iteration.

Comment: @chqrlie: I see my point of confusion; I thought some pointers into the p[i] string were used afterward; q isn't, but I'm not quite clear what's going on with x and y.

Comment: `x` and `y` are the word to search for and the word to replace with.  They are fragments of the `sir` argument which gets modified by `strtok`.  This is very cumbersome, like the rest of this function.